# Is it ok to have a unique account number as a partition key

Tags: cassandra

I have an application where the partition key is a unique customer account number. Is it good to have it this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only going to be querying by account number thats fine. Design the tables around how you want to query them.

Comment: How do i know if cassandra is the right choice for my solution. My gut feeling is that rdbms is better in this case. Kindly advice. Below are my requirements.                                                    1. Financial data to store sensitive info.                   2. No real need for scale.                                        3. Max one or two tables but columns might change in the future.                                              4. Daily updates on few rows.                                  5. More reads than writes.